# Showing text in Android ListAdapter on this specific case

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, listadapter

I am trying to build a simple TV-Guide for Android. To make that, I am using RSS from one site. I parse XML and now, I'd like to show it. The idea is a List that displays Station, Whats currently on the show and date, and when I press on some item in the list it will give me a new Activity that shows the full schedule of some TV station. I've managed to separate parts of Whole TV program in just separate Strings (like: 06:00 News; 07:15 Movie). And I even managed to separate it so it fills String[][] (like: |06|,|00|,|News| ; |07|,|15|,|Movie|). And my Idea was to check which one is closest to real time and to display it.

Well, currently my App displays TV Station, WHOLE program (schedule), and Date. And I want it to display just whats currently showed. Can anybody help me with this one?

Here is class in which I want to do it:  (I also have Parser class and Main class with just buttons and URLs of XMLs)

```
public class Pomocna extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static String url =null;

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "pubDate";
static final String KEY_DESC = "encoded";

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int DSQ=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int DMQ=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    url = in.getStringExtra("A");


    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    //ArrayList<String[][]> nekaj = new ArrayList<String[][]>();


    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); //get XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // get DOM elem.
    //doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    //loop
    for (int i=0; i< nl.getLength(); i++){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        //add to map
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, Vracanje1(parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE)));
        map.put(KEY_DATE, Vracanje2(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE)));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue3(e,KEY_DESC));

        //NEKO FRCERANJE -=- POCETAK

        String pvp = parser.getValue3(e,KEY_DESC);
        char[] rast = pvp.toCharArray();
        int brojac = 0;
        for(int q=0; q<pvp.length(); q++){
            if(rast[q]=='*') brojac++;
        }

        String[][] niz= new String[brojac][3];

        int bf1=0;
        int bf3=0;

        int oo=0;
        for(int q=0; q<pvp.length(); q++){
            if(rast[q]=='*'){
                bf3=bf1;
                bf1=q;

                String lol = pvp.substring(bf3, bf1);

                // SEPARATE STRING: LOL
                // IT MUST HAVE 3 PARTS: HOUR, MINUTE, AND DESCRIPTION

                if(oo==0){
                    String ps=lol.substring(0,2);
                    String ds=lol.substring(3,5);
                    String ts=lol.substring(6,lol.length());

                    niz[oo][0]=ps;
                    niz[oo][1]=ds;
                    niz[oo][2]=ts;  
                }
                if(oo>0){
                    String ps=lol.substring(1,3);
                    String ds=lol.substring(4,6);
                    String ts=lol.substring(7,lol.length());

                    niz[oo][0]=ps;
                    niz[oo][1]=ds;
                    niz[oo][2]=ts;
                }
                oo++;
            }
        }

        //NEKO FRCERANJE -=- KRAJ

        menuItems.add(map);
        //nekaj.add(niz);
    }


    //DISPLAY WHAT's CURRENTLY ON PROGRAM
    //USE TIME TO COMPARE AND SHOW



    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE}, new int[]{
            R.id.title, R.id.description, R.id.date
    });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //singleView
    ListView lv = getListView();

}

public String Vracanje1(String bq){
    int p1=bq.length();
    int p2=p1-10;
    StringBuilder sbp= new StringBuilder(bq);
    sbp.delete(p2, p1);
    String ses=sbp.toString();

    return ses;
}
public String Vracanje2(String bq){
    int p1=bq.length();
    int p2=p1-14;
    StringBuilder sbp=new StringBuilder(bq);
    sbp.delete(p2, p1);
    String ses = sbp.toString();

    return ses;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding the way You're doing won't be acceptable to any TV-program application, because usually program has many channels with many programs and parsing and analysing the data in UI thread will (sooner or later) cause ANRs. I would suggest You to consider use of separate service and content provider to let UI thread do only UI-related stuff and leave data processing to corresponding components. It would be faster and easier to find/process data via sqlite in provider.

Regarding a question about finding closest data - You could sort arrays and when find closest one (e.g. just iterating from the beginning).

Comment: Ty. About this first answer, I do not understand, did you mean of using Database over RSS concept or what? .. I have no access to database, that's why I must parse XML. About other.. ty, I forgot about that

Comment: I mean to use Database for storing data after parsing. Checkout this video from google i/o - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE which has complete explanation of the concept.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using REST and all those things with services, but since this is just like 20-30 programs, I saw no need :D .. but ty

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sandstar, but I'm not sure if what you're asking is how to filter the data or how to **show the data**? In this case it is the matter of updating the `ListAdapter`. This means, when you want to show only the most recent program, you need to provide the adapter a list of maps containing *only* the map with the data for the latest show. This means you should *filter the data before applying the adapter to the* `ListView`. If you want to have more control over the adapter you might consider extending the `ArrayAdapter` which also allows you to *add/clear* the data of the existing adapter.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about showing the data, to be speciffic, You see that List containing Map. That's nice feature, but the thing I need is that list to accept a matrix (String[][]) and to show it.. is that possible?

Comment: Nope. But instead of filling the 'menuItems' in the parsing loop, you should fill it after that. For example: String title = niz[lastRecentShowIndex][0]; String date = niz[lastRecentShowIndex][1]; String show = ...; and after that: map.put(KEY_TITLE, title); map.put(KEY_DATE, date); map.put(KEY_DESC, show); menuItems.add(map);  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems, ....

Comment: Well, thats a very good Idea, but, it may be that I am stupid, but I do not understand how to get lastRecentShowIndex ...

Comment: Well, you could iterate trough niz[i][j] and compare the current time with the previous time (using a.compareTo(b)) and then store its index(i) if it's "bigger" than the previous. When you come to the end of the loop, you will have the index you are looking for. I think you can figure out the implementation alone. Pozdrav! ;)